# worse case scenario: launched two copies of a program which appends lines to a file

Tags: parallel-processing

I have a Python program which performs a simple operation on a file:

```
with open(self.cache_filename_url, "a", encoding="utf8") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', lineterminator='\n')
    w.writerow([cache_url, rpd_products])
```

As you can see it just opens the file and appends a CSV line to it. It does this a lot, in a loop.

I accidentally ran two copies of this program simultaneously, so I think they would have been appending to the file simultaneously. I am trying to determine the worst-case-scenario for file corruption.

Do you think the writes would at least be atomic operations in this case? For example this **wouldn't** be a problem for me:

```
old line
old line
new line written by instance 1
new line written by instance 2
new line written by one
```

This **would** be a problem for me:

```
old line
old line
[half of new line written by instance 1] [half of new line by instance 2]
etc
```

To put it another way, is it possible for the two append operations to "interfere" with each other?

EDIT: I am using Windows 7

Comment: this will depend on the system and the sharing mode set.

Comment: What do you mean by sharing mode? I am using Windows 7. I guess you are referring to locks of some kind, but I don't know what the default behavior is, so that's my question.

Comment: in python 2.x on windows, it should be exclusive mode, which really means only one file can open for writing.

Answer (score 1):

Opening the same file multiple times in shared write mode can definitely be problematic. And, if they don't open in shared mode, you'll get one of them throwing exceptions that it cannot open the file.

If SHARED mode:
Both instances will have their own internal pointer. In most cases, they will probably write independently. You could get:

```
Process A opens file, sets pointer to end (byte 1024)
Process B opens file, sets pointer to end (byte 1024)
Process B writes at byte 1024 and closes file
Process A writes at byte 1024 and closes file.
```

Both processes will have written to the file at the same location. You've basically lost the record from Process B, and depending on how the close works (if it truncates), if the lines it writes are different lengths, you could get part of Process B if the line was longer.

If it is in EXCLUSIVE mode, one process will fail to open the file, and whatever exception handling you have will kick in.

Which mode you are in can be system dependent, as Python doesn't seem to provide any mechanisms for controlling the share mode.

Comment: Taking a step back, are "shared mode" and "exclusive mode" Python-level concepts, or OS-level concepts?

Comment: And while I can't change it, can I at least figure out what mode would have been used?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I ran a check on my file, and I did indeed have corrupted partial lines (the case under "This **would** be a problem for me" in my question)

It's unfortunate, especially since it implies you could have problems even when you **intend** to share a file between two processes.

I am still interested in any pointers on how to avoid this outcome. I will hold off on marking an answer as accepted for now. (The other answer is good, but doesn't provide enough details on these modes or how to determine which will be used.)